# sencha Touch horizontal scroll and Hbox

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2, horizontal-scrolling

Hi i need little help with the scenario i am facing hard to get. i have a horizontal list view of images i want to show only three images on the screen and with center image highlighted.

I tried carousel but only the image highlighted will be scrollable, i want the horizontal kind of smooth scrolling.

Is something like using hbox panel on top of horizontal list view works?

```
var superpanel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'hbox',             
    items: [
        {
           xtype: 'panel',
           id: 'panel_1',
           width: '100%',
           layout: 'fit',
           items: [
                {
                   xtype: 'list',
                   flex:1,
                   id: 'list1',
                   store: 'samplestore1'
                }
           ]
         }
    ]
 });
```

can someone help with the scenario how to achieve this.
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need carousel for this. Dataview will serve the purpose. Check out this dude:

```
 Ext.define('Example.view.HorizontalList', {
            extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
            xtype: 'horizontallist',
            config: {
                inline: {
                    wrap: false
                },
                scrollable: {
                    direction: 'horizontal'
                },

                //set the itemtpl to show the fields for the store
                itemTpl: '{name} {image}',

                //bind the store to this list
                store: 'xyz'
            }
        });
```

You can also check [this](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-horizontal/).

Comment: but i want the center element should be highlighted..it should be like center frame is fixed and images should pass by the frame

Comment: @teekib: have you tried anything for that? If yes then post that. I guess this is doable via css.